# Как заполнить DataFrame данными из другого DataFrame по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два DataFrame: первый `DF1` состоит из двух столбцов "название" и "статус", второй `DF2` состоит из одного столбца "название".

Как добавить в `DF2` столбец "статус" и заполнить его соответствующим значением из `DF1`, с условием что `DF2.название=DF1.название`?

Как написать эту функцию?

```
 df1 = food[['name','state']]
 a='!'
 b=[item for item in df1.name if a in item]
 df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([b]).transpose()
 df2.columns=[['name']]
 df2['state'] = df2['name'].map(df1.set_index('name')['state'])
```

Выдает:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-124-64a28e806b82> in <module>()
 ----> 1 df2['state'] = df2['name'].map(df1.set_index('name')['state'])

 D:\prog\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
    4375                 return self[name]
 -> 4376             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    4377 
    4378     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Фрагмент df1[:4]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фрагмент df2[:4]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

Исходные DataFrame'ы:

```
In [73]: df1
Out[73]:
    name       state
0  name1  successful
1  name2      failed
2  name3  successful
3  name4      failed

In [74]: df2
Out[74]:
    name
0  name3
1  name4
2  name1
```

Решение:

```
In [75]: df2['state'] = df2['name'].map(df1.set_index('name')['state'])
```

Результат:

```
In [76]: df2
Out[76]:
    name       state
0  name3  successful
1  name4      failed
2  name1  successful
```

Comment: Ошибка:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: @Uladzislau, приведите небольшой пример вашего DF в вопросе

Comment: привел пример своего кода

Comment: @Uladzislau, работает решение?

Comment: на сколько я понял функция .map подходит к данным list и не подходит к data frame. Поэтому я нашел другое решение для моей задачи. Как мне кажется более простое, чем первоначальное

Comment: @Uladzislau, для разных исходных данных используются разные решения - то что отлично работает для Series, не всегда будет работать для DataFrame и наоборот. Именно поэтому очень полезно приводить воспроизводимый пример данных в вопросе (ссылка в комментарии под вопросом).